# Include List of Class When Storing Object in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a User class in Flutter that looks like the following:

```
class User {
    User({this.name, this.grade, this.workouts});
    String name;
    int grade;
    List<Workout> workouts;

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': _name,
    'grade': _grade,
    'workout': workouts,
  };
}
```

and a Workout Class that looks like this:

```
class Workout {
    Workout({this.date, this.shots});
    String date;
    int shots;
}
```

I want to add the User to a firestore collection like this: `Firestore.instance.collection('users').add(_user.toJson());`
but when I do this I get an:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Workout'
```

What would be a way to workaround this to have my JSON schema be essentially:

```
{
    "name": name,
    "grade": grade,
    "workouts": [
        {
            "date": date,
            "shots": shots,
        }
    ] 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "toJson" function is incorrect. As the error message suggests, you are adding your own "workout" class instances inside your "map".

try this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> workoutsJson = List();
    workouts.forEach((wkt) => workoutsJson.add(wkt.toJson()));
        return {
        'name': _name,
        'grade': _grade,
        'workouts': workoutsJson,
        };
    }
```

and then in your Workouts class, add a function toJson() just like you did for User class.